# function including waiting for bootstrap tab to be shown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

Trying to figure how to go about building a function which includes a step waiting for a bootstrap tab to be shown and then continuing the function. Could use event shown but only want this to be carried out when function is executed. Any hints?

Basic code:

```
function test(){
   $('a[href="#tab1"]').tab('show'); //go to tab
   $("a[href='#tab1']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
     //do something else. However this is carried out also outside of function...only want it carried out inside function
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you *split* the function in two parts, the part which runs before the tab is shown and the part that runs only after the tab is shown.

HIH

```
function test(){
   //run first part
   $('a[href="#tab1"]').tab('show'); //go to tab - I assume this line triggers the tab to be shown, right? otherwise you could use this one:

   //next line *will* actually execute the code inside the event handler 
   $('a[href="#tab1"]').trigger('shown.bs.tab'); //go to tab
}

//this code runs on page load BUT...
$("a[href='#tab1']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    //...code in here runs only when this line runs: $('a[href="#tab1"]').trigger('shown.bs.tab');
    //run second part
});
```

Comment: isn't the shown event available also outside the function in this case? want the shown event only to be executed inside the function.

Comment: @KevinLindmark 1. did you try it? 2. I don't know what you mean by *available also outside the function*, when you attach a handler to an event, the handler itself is not executed in that moment, it's a dormant function waiting for the event to be triggered. so, as you asked in your question, the handler will only be carried out/executed inside `test()`, after `$('a[href="#tab1"]').tab('show');`, I'll add some notes to the answer, please let me know